# ASP.NET - Enums are not saved with proper value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to save enum values with from a Select using the following code:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].WarmUp)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ExerciseName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CoolDown)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].MomentOfTheDay)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ExerciseWeek)</td>
            <td><select asp-for="@Model[j].Days" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SampleMvcApp.Models.Days>()"></select></td>
            <td>
                @if (j > 0)
                {
                    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        j++;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
  public ActionResult SaveList(int id, List<Exercise> exerciseList)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                foreach (var exercise in exerciseList)
                {
                    _context.Exercise.Add(exercise);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

It is supposed to save multiple rows at once, and it works perfectly except for the Select part. 
The first enum value is saved properly, however, the rest are inserted as 0. I've tried debugging but I just can't find my mistake.

Comment: Why don't you use `@Html.DropDownListFor`?

Comment: @GertArnold I've tried but I can't get it to work. Do you mind giving me an example of how to use DropDownList with Enums? I found a few ways online but they seem to overcomplicate, in my opinion.